# Best way to retrive the items using Cosmos Client

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working on CosmosDB and trying to retrieve items from CosmosDB using Cosmos Client.
I tried below two scenarios and able to get items from DB. However, I just want to know which approach is good in terms of RU's and performance.

**Approach 1**

```
        var container = // Read Container;
        var sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c";

        QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
        var queryResultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Family>(queryDefinition);

        List<Family> families = new List<Familyt>();

        while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<Family> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
            foreach (Family family in currentResultSet)
            {
                families.Add(family);
            }
        }
```

**Approach 2**

```
        var container = // Read Container
        var families = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Family>(true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

**`GetItemLinqQueryable`** is not async you will have to use [**`ReadNextAsync`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getitemlinqqueryable?view=azure-dotnet) to query the data and is the right way to use LINQ with Cosmos v3 API